# Waiting for a text change in WatiN

Tags: ajax, testing, watin, wait

I am trying to test a web page that has ajax calls to update a price.
An ajax call is fired on page load to update an initially empty div.

This is the extension method I'm using to wait for a change in the inner text of the div.

```
public static void WaitForTextChange(this IE ie, string id)
{
    string old = ie.Element(id).Text;
    ie.Element(id).WaitUntil(!Find.ByText(old));
}
```

However it's not pausing even though when I write out the old value and ie.Element(id).Text after the wait, they are both null. I can't debug as this acts as a pause.

Can the Find.ByText not handle nulls or have I got something wrong.

Has anyone got some code working similar to this?

Answer (score 2):

I found my own solution in the end after delving into WatiN's constraints.

Here's the solution:

```
public class TextConstraint : Constraint
{
    private readonly string _text;
    private readonly bool _negate;

    public TextConstraint(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
        _negate = false;
    }

    public TextConstraint(string text, bool negate)
    {
        _text = text;
        _negate = negate;
    }

    public override void WriteDescriptionTo(TextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("Find text to{0} match {1}.", _negate ? " not" : "", _text);
    }

    protected override bool MatchesImpl(IAttributeBag attributeBag, ConstraintContext context)
    {
        return (attributeBag.GetAdapter<Element>().Text == _text) ^ _negate;
    }
}
```

And the updated extension method:

```
public static void WaitForTextChange(this IE ie, Element element)
{
    string old = element.Text;
    element.WaitUntil(new TextConstraint(old, true));
}
```

It assumes that the old value will be read before the change so there's a slight chance of a race condition if you use it too long after setting off the update but it works for me.

Comment: Actually. I've hit another problem. Sometimes the price I'm updating doesn't change, in which case I want to timeout and then carry on with the next user action but using 

.WaitUntil(new TextConstraint(old, true), 2000);

Just gets stuck.